# Buscar palabras y coincidencias en una cadena de texto

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

tengo el siguiente código:

`Estaciones = Estaciones.Where(e => e.DireccionRural.Contains(address));`

Es buscar una dirección que esta almacenada en una BD.

por ejemplo: **CALLE 37 A # 11-70**

al ingresar la dirección de ejemplo en el [input] así ta cual, no hay problema y me trae el resultado, el problema esta cuando ingreso lo siguiente:

**CALLE 37 A 11-70**

Como ven, he quitado el carácter especial (#) de la cadena de dirección, al colocarlo así no me trae ningún resultado, la idea es que me traiga la dirección sin importar que carácter quite ya sea el (-) o en este caso si quito el (11) y que me quede **CALLE 37 A -70** así.

Alguna sugerencia, muchas gracias

Comment: podrias usar un like y llenar la consulta de caracteres opcionales... pero no hay una solucion a esto... tal vez segun la base que uses, la base tenga alguna solucion para estas busquedas...

Comment: a que te refieres con la base

Comment: la base de datos.. o tenes solo estructuras en memoria?

Comment: le di una solucion, al momento que usuario coloque la direccion CALLE 37 A # 11-70 por debajo lo formateo con js y queda CALLE37A1170 y en la bd para que el contains sirva tambien doy formato con replace("#","").trim() y espacios(" "), puntos(.) y guiones(-) y asi tambien me lo compara y lo formatea, muchas gracias